# matching exact string with Serverspec (rspec)

Tags: ruby, windows, rspec, chef-infra

I would like to come up with a test which would fail, unless the string matches exactly.

Output which should lead to a failure

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> auditpol.exe /get /subcategory:'User Account Management'
System audit policy
Category/Subcategory                      Setting
Account Management
  User Account Management                 Success and Failure
```

Output which should lead to success:

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> auditpol.exe /get /subcategory:'User Account Management'
System audit policy
Category/Subcategory                      Setting
Account Management
  User Account Management                 Success
```

And various permutations of below test which passes despite hours of googling and experimenting

```
describe command("auditpol.exe /get /subcategory:'User Account Management'") do 
  its(:stdout){should match(/User Account Management                 Success/)}
end
```

The most promising test is this, however it wants the exact literal match of entire output, not just the string in question:

```
describe command("auditpol.exe /get /subcategory:'User Account Management'") do 
  its(:stdout){should eq(/User Account Management                 Success/)}
end
```

Thanks

Comment: The command to set the policy `auditpol.exe /set /subcategory:'User Account Management' /success:enable /failure:enable`

Comment: To give an update on this issue, I've long moved over to using Inspec instead of Serverspec

Answer (score 1):

try to work with the $-sign.

```
describe command("auditpol.exe /get /subcategory:'User Account Management'") do 
  its(:stdout){should match(/User Account Management                 Success$/)}
end
```

sources:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html
and many many more

Comment: Nope, unfortunately no go. Looks like it wants literal $ `Failure/Error: its(:stdout){should match(/User Account Management                 Success$/)}`
`expected "System audit policy\r\r\nCategory/Subcategory
Setting\r\nAccount Management\r\n  User Account Management
Success\r\r\n" to match /User Account ManagementSuccess$/`
Diff:
  @@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
  -/User Account Management                 Success$/
  +System audit policy
  +Category/Subcategory                      Setting
  +Account Management
  +  User Account Management                 Success`

Comment: Then you can work with `should_not` instead of `should` or try to rewrite your command to different and easier to match output.